# Why greedy leads to best among all epsilon-soft Monte Carlo

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning

In the RL book of Barto and Sutton, the authors give the definition of epsilon-soft and the pseudocode. I understand this step proves that we can keep improving a epsilon-soft policy. But I don't understand why this results in a policy that is better than all epsilon-soft policies.

I seems that the authors are proving this later (below the "below red notation"). But I really have no idea how it works. It creates a new environment, get a optimal value function for that, say the value function computed before is the same as this one. Yeah, it can prove the policy is optimal is that environment, but how does it relate to all epsilon-soft policies. Epsilon-soft treats all actions same, with possibility bigger than opsilon / action size. But clearly, the new environment is doing something different. And One thing that also comfuses me is that why we need a new environment while in fact the environment is unknown to us. Thanks!

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 1]